# Increasing the page numbers of paging in SharePoint search

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, display-template

I am looking for some help on search display template. I need to change the code in Control_SearchResults.html file to increase the no of page numbers. Can someone please help me to get this.

On initial load, search page shows only two pages. How can I display 1 to 5 with previous and next arrow on the initial loading of the search page ?

Answer (score 0):

By updating search result web part property

```
<MaxPagesAfterCurrent>4</MaxPagesAfterCurrent>
```

ResultScriptWebPartMaxPagesAfterCurrent property

Specify the maximum number of pages after the current page of results for which to display paging links